# How to get the html content loaded with jquery load function

Tags: jquery

I have created dynamic div element as shown below

```
var newDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div')); 
newDiv1.attr('id','nedi');
newDiv1.attr('style','position:absolute;top:10;right:15;');
```

I am trying to load html content  with the following line of code but ended up in vain!

```
$('#newDiv1').load('new_one_2.html');
```

my folder structure as shown in the image attached. Please help me to load html content with jquery load

[image: Please see attached image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given a different ID. Use:

```
$('#nedi').load('new_one_2.html');
```

Variable name is different from `id`. Or you should use something like:

```
$.get("new_one_2.html", function (res) {
  newDiv1.html(res);
});
```

Comment: not working for me. may be I have problem with relative path?

Comment: @Baji Kindly show me a screenshot of how your are executing it, and show the console too. Include the full browser window, with address bar, console, and the page.

Comment: 1.This is how I executing http://localhost:9000/Jquery_mobile_2/www/new_one.html in chrome.2.The following is the piece of code I want to execute             var newDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div')); 
                            newDiv1.attr('id','nedi');
                            newDiv1.attr('style','position:absolute;top:10;right:15;');
                            $('#nedi').load('new_one_2.html');
                           $.get("new_one_2.html", function (res) {
                                       newDiv1.html(res);
                                  });

Comment: Worked for me when I don't create div tag dynamically.any problem with dynamic creation?

Comment: @Baji Can you please change that code `var newDiv1 = $(document.createElement('div'));` to `var newDiv1 = $("<div />");`

Comment: @Baji **You are not appending it to the body!!!** Man!!! Give this at the end `newDiv1.appendTo("body");`

Comment: @Baji Ha ha... Case closed.